# Execute php file from website after clicking a button (apache)

Tags: php, apache, button, execute

The php file is in web site directory (`/var/www`) and I would like to execute it from `index.html` which is in the same directory.

The php file:

```
    <?php
    exec("sudo -u pi /home/pi/camcv/camcv .. ");
    ?>
```

Can be run by typing `php /var/www/script.php` in command line from anywhere in the system, it executes properly (camera flashes, opens the window with picture, no errors). I would need it to be executable by `www-data` user from website.

I know there are many options, I have tried `submit` forms, `onClick` actions, sending a parameter ( `$_POST['xy']`) then watching it with "if" structure in php file, `AJAX` in form of `XMLHttpRequest` and in form of `$.ajax` , I tried to include javascript `jquery.min.js` and have tried to add permissions in `sudoers` or changed ownership of folders/files with allowing to read/write/execute... all without achieving the goal.

So my questions are:

-Does someone have a bulletproof way to make this work ?

-Can you tell me what exactly do I have to add in `sudoers` ?

Thanks for any advice.

PS: Few of the tries did redirect me to page `http://(ip)/script.php` so there is at least some response from the buttons. Also, XMLHttpRequest did work on Changing the text on webpage (reading and posting txt file).

PSS: The function does not require any return information, I would need the page to stay on the site with the button, possibly not reloading.

Comment: www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL ??

Comment: Yes, but that would expose the page entirely .. but since its for study reasons I opened it as you wrote .. still nothing happened .. I just have found out that it only reacts if the user is "pi" but the part of command "-u pi" should take care of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to resolve this problem with jQuery:

```
<!doctype html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$("#clickme").bind('click', function(){
        $.get( "script.php", function( data ) {
        $( ".result" ).append( data );
        });
    });
});
</script>
<input type="submit" id="clickme" value="TEST">
<div class="result">Result...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

if your "script.php" has any response you will get it in the div container

Comment: thanks for fast response, I tried the code, but it seems not to be working. Maybe its because only user "pi" can open the camera window .. I will try to make error log to see what it writes .. Do you know any basic function that would be visible if it succeeded ? Something like mkdir but with less interference with system.

Comment: You sir deserve a medal :) It is working, and everything works fine. Also .. one advice: if you are calling a hard program (face recognition), it is really adviced to go through the program and chceck for full filepaths and problems with using external display.